How to set up AWS Lambda function to run Helius API
I have some Lambda function currently set to use the standard Mainnet-beta API endpoint.
https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com
I want to change this to my Helius API endpoints (https://mainnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=XXXXXXX) but Lambda does not have a dedicated IP address or domain name and I hate to open the API to all users. Does anybody have any experience setting this up for Lambda functions? What is the best way to get this to work with Helius API?

Unfortunately this was no easy feat and it took some AWS reconfiguration to work. Here's the doc for anybody else that runs into similar issues..
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/generate-a-static-outbound-ip-address-using-a-lambda-function-amazon-vpc-and-a-serverless-architecture.html
